# Java: How to join 3 linear arrays in one CSV file with 3 columns

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I'm scraping web content using puppeteer. I managed to scrape the content I want, into three separate arrays with the same number of elements each. What I need is to join the three linear arrays in such a way that each linear array becomes a different column.

I put together the three arrays in one object, and the log output is as follows:

```
    { header1: 
       [ ' string1 ',
         ' string2 ',
         ' string3 '],

      header2: 
       [ ' string4 ',
         ' string5 ',
         ' string6 '], 

      header3: 
       [ ' string7 ',
         ' string8 ',
         ' string9 ']  
     }
```

JSON.stringify will change it to this:

> ```
> '{"header1":[" string1 "," string2 "," string3 "],"header2":["string4","string5","string6"],"header3":["string7","string8","string9"]}'
> ```

What I need is a CSV file like this:

> ```
> header1,header2,header3
> string1,string4,string7
> string2,string5,string8
> string3,string6,string9
> ```

I'm sure this is extremely easy, but I'm clearly a beginner. Most info I found deals with joining arrays on top of one another or parsing JSON objects with proper table syntax, which doesn't quite fit with what I have here. Thanks.

Comment: You can put that in a `map`: each header will be the `key`, and each `value` will represent the `3 elements array`. After that you can just write as a first row the keys, then you write the values (for each key at a time)

Comment: @jschnasse you are right. Done.

Answer (score 1):

> What I need is to join the three linear arrays in such a way that each linear array becomes a different column.

**Step 1**

Define a method to do the job, e.g.

```
public String arraysToString(String[] first, String[]... arrays) {
    return "Not implemented yet!";
}
```

The method will take a variable number of `String[]` arrays.

**Step 2**

Define some code to test the method, e.g.

```
@Test // No clue what this is? Google it - "junit", "tdd", "assertions" ...!
public void testArraysToString() {
    String[] h1 = { "header1", "string1", "string2", "string3" };
    String[] h2 = { "header2", "string4", "string5", "string6" };
    String[] h3 = { "header3", "string7", "string8", "string9" };
    String result = arraysToString(h1, h2, h3);
    String expected = "header1,header2,header3\nstring1,string4,string7\nstring2,string5,string8\nstring3,string6,string9\n";
    org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(expected, result);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

**Step 3**

Try to write some code until your first test case succeeds e.g.

```
public String arraysToString(String[] first, String[]... arrays) {
    for (String[] cur : arrays) {
        if (cur.length != first.length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Precondition failed. Arrays do not have the same length.");
        }
    }
    StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
        strb.append(first[i]);
        for (String[] array : arrays) {
            strb.append(",");
            strb.append(array[i]);
        }
        strb.append("\n");
    }
    return strb.toString();
}
```

This will print

```
header1,header2,header3
string1,string4,string7
string2,string5,string8
string3,string6,string9
```

> Note: If your implementation does not behave like expected you are now in a good position to post a question at stackoverflow.com. Just paste your test code and your code together with stack trace and a short description.

**Step 4**

Add more test cases and enhance the implementation

Answer (score 0):

I found a way. First I built a JSON object from the 3 arrays:

```
for(var JSONobj = [], i = 0; i < array1.length; ++i) 
    JSONobj.push({ array1: array1[i], array2: array2[i], array3: array3[i]})
```

Then I used some more piece of code I found to turn it into CSV and export it. I needed json2csv and fs libs.

```
const Json2csvParser = require('json2csv').Parser;
const fields = ['array1', 'array2', 'array3'];


const json2csvParser = new Json2csvParser({ fields });
const csv = json2csvParser.parse(JSONobj);

console.log(csv);

var fs = require('fs');

fs.writeFile('name.csv', csv, 'utf8', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Some error occured - file either not saved or corrupted file saved.');
  } else {
    console.log('It\'s saved!');
  }
});
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve with `const` ? See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.9. All together your code is not very self explanatory and therefore will hardly help others. You should really add some info about the libraries you are using, etc.

Comment: Sorry I'm an absolute beginner. What I needed is to take three separate arrays and build a CSV table, where each array is one column. So I basically merged the 3 separate unidimensional arrays ("array1", "array2", "array3") into one array-of-objects JSON object ("JSONobj"). Then I turned that into a CSV file and exported it. json2csv is a lib that converts any JSON object into CSV format. fs lib serves the purpose of writing the CSV file.